# PDF Files in your App - Not Storage Card

Tags: android-intent

Is it possible to store the PDF files you want in the Res folder, under a seperate folder and then read them. I've got the code to read them from the SD Card or anywhere on the phone, but I would like to have them included with the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes its very possible. Its the same way app icons work too. You simply call the file by its resource. I presume you're trying to code for android?

Comment: Yes, android. so in the Intent, you just reference the R.pdf.xxxxx instead of "/sdcard/xxxxx

Comment: something like that. However you dont need to use the file extensions. and you must add it to the xml template on the main project.